# calculating occurrences in two columns

Tags: r

I am writing a code that counts the occurrences of values in a certain columns(c2,c3,c4,...) if values in another column (c1) exist and then dividing by the total occurrences in c1 to get the percentage where both happen together. That said, if any of the cells has NA values, it doesn't count.

so far i have written the code as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(table)

for (col in 1:ncol(df)){
  x = 0
  for(row in 1:nrow(df)){

    if ((is.na(df[row,1])==F) & (is.na(df[row,col])==F)){
       x = x + 1
    }
    p <- x / colSums(!is.na(df))[1]
  }
  print(p)
}
```

it gives me the correct results but all with reference to column c1 as follows:

```
C1 
                        1 
C1 
                0.8666667 
C1
                0.5333333 
C1 
                0.5333333 
C1 
                      0.8
```

How can I get it include the name of each column instead of referencing to C1 for all the values? and also how do I get p to be sorted?

Thanks

Comment: It would help to see some or all of `df` as plain text; you can paste the output of `dput(df)` if not too large.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- tibble(
  var_name = names(df),
  prop = p
) %>%
 arrange(p)
```

This should give you a new tibble (dataframe) where you have a column of names from your original dataframe and a column with the values you're calculating.